# Checking if a macro is called on bare application of itself

Tags: macros, expansion

So I want to create a command `\setcol{A}{n}` which should produce `{A}^{[n]}` when called like this I also want `\setcol{\setcol{A}{n}}{m}` to produce `{A}^{[n][m]}` rather than `{A^{[n]}}^{[m]}`.

But, and this is what blocks just simply redefining `\setcol` when evaluated inside the macro `\setcol`, I want `\setcol{(\setcol{A}{n} + B)}{m}` to evaluate to `{({A}^{[n]}+B)}^{[m]}`.

So, basically I need to check if the argument to `\setcol` is a bare call to `\setcol` and do something different in that case.   How can I do that?  I feel there must be some kind of check with `\ifx` but I'm a bit fuzzy on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by testing whether the argument contains exactly 3 braced groups or tokens and if so whether the first of those tokens is `\setcol`. If that is the case output the special case, else use the normal output.

The following uses `expl3` to achieve this (because it already contains everything we need for those tests).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \setcol {m m}
  {
    \bool_lazy_and:nnTF
      { \int_compare_p:nNn { \tl_count:n {#1} } = 3 }
      { \tl_if_head_eq_meaning_p:nN {#1} \setcol }
      {
        \pgerdes_setcol_special:nnnn #1 {#2}
      }
      {
        \pgerdes_setcol_normal:nn {#1} {#2}
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \pgerdes_setcol_special:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
  {
    {#2} \sp { [#3] [#4] }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \pgerdes_setcol_normal:nn #1 #2
  {
    {#1} \sp { [#2] }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\setcol{A}{n}$

$\setcol{\setcol{A}{n}}{m}$

$\setcol{(\setcol{A}{n} + B)}{m}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Since you already had the idea to use `\ifx`, here is how I would've done it without `expl3` (so this might be a bit more educational), the idea remains the same, test whether it's 3 tokens and the first one is `\setcol`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\setcol[1]
  {%
    \setcol@ifthree{#1}
      {%
        \setcol@special#1{#1}%
      }
      {%
        \setcol@normal{#1}%
      }%
  }
\newcommand\setcol@ifthree[1]
  {%
    \ifnum\numexpr\setcol@count#1\setcol@stop=3
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  }
\newcommand\setcol@count[1]
  {%
    \ifx\setcol@stop#1%
    \else
      \expandafter+\expandafter1\expandafter\setcol@count
    \fi
  }
\newcommand\setcol@special[5]
  {%
    \ifx\setcol#1%
      {#2}^{[#3][#5]}%
    \else
      {#4}^{[#5]}%
    \fi
  }
\newcommand\setcol@normal[2]
  {%
    {#1}^{[#2]}%
  }
\newcommand*\setcol@stop{\setcol@stop}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\setcol{A}{n}$

$\setcol{\setcol{A}{n}}{m}$

$\setcol{(\setcol{A}{n} + B)}{m}$
\end{document}
```

(output like above)

Comment: thanks greatly!